# My question is about how to manualy recover the Woocommerce 'my-account' page and fix Wordpress admin logout issue?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, restore

I'm facing an issue recently regarding "WOOCOMMERCE" plugin based on that my (Lets say) a couple of question arises.

1. At first I was unable to Logout from the WordPress admin, basically it did logged out but instead of being redirected its leading to a white screen of death.
2. After going through hours of debugging process here's what I came up with (Lets say) a temporary conclusion and I'm assuming that the Log out issue was causing due to the deletion of the "WOOCOMMERCE" my-account page (as per the redirection url :- http://webmateinfo.net/demo/HTML/wp-login.php?action=logout&_wpnonce=dfd0d59919)
3. Now when I'm proceeding to re-install the deleted pages from the tools tab (Woocommerce->status->tools) I found that the option "restore woocommerce pages" is missing.

I would really be grateful & appreciate the help as I'm already running out of time.